# html select list value not passing on to PHP

Tags: php, html, select, data-retrieval

I have a form in which values get inserted and passed to PHP, everything was working till I thought about inserting a select value, and this one always gets passed on to the database as 0. This is the form:

```
<form name="myForm" id="register" action="register.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<select name="Year" form="register">

  <option value="year1">1</option>
  <option value="year2">2</option>
  <option  value="year3">3</option>
  </select>
```

This is how I retrieve all my variables, but this select one doesn't seem to work.

PHP:

```
        $value7 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Year']);
```

Thank you!

Comment: change **<option value="1">year1</option>**

Comment: check my it's sure work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  this

`<option value="year1">1</option>`

to this

`<option value="1">year1</option>`

PHP Code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
echo mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Year']);
?>
```

HTML code

```
<select name="Year" form="register">

  <option value="1">year1</option>
  <option value="2">year2</option>
  <option  value="3">year3</option>
  </select>
<input type='submit' >
</form>
```

Comment: Solved, thank you! I hadn't understood that it was the value in Value that was getting passed on, and not what I put in the middle. Thanks again, solved!

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
<select name="Year" form="register">

  <option value="year1">1</option>
  <option value="year2">2</option>
  <option  value="year3">3</option>
  </select>
```

to

```
<select name="Year" form="register">

  <option value="1">year1</option>
  <option value="2">year2</option>
  <option  value="3">year3</option>
  </select>
```